# granting write permissions to a group to a folder

Tags: permissions, files, group

How can I grant write permission to one group?

I have two users (`alex` and `ben`).

`alex` is member of group `alex` and of group `consult`.

`ben` is member of group `ben` and of group `consult`.

I want to grant read-write access to both `alex` and `ben` on the folder `consult_documents`.

If I make `alex` the owner of the directory `consult_documents` and I grant `775` access to the directory `consult_documents`, `ben` and `alex` will be able to access the folder, I think.

But will this allow `ben` access to `alex`'s other folders as well?
If a user is in two groups, does that mean that all the members from both groups get the same permissions on all folders?

Comment: Do you want alex and ben to be able to create files in consult_documents and allow them both read/write access on those documents ?

Answer (score 60):

Granting 775 permissions on a directory doesn't automatically mean that all users in a certain group will gain `rwx` access to it. They need to either be the owner of the directory or to belong to the directory's group:

```
$ ls -ld some_dir
drwxrwxr-x 2 alex consult 4096 Feb 20 10:10 some_dir/
              ^     ^
              |     |_____ directory's group
              |___________ directory's owner
```

So, in order to allow both alex and ben to have write access to `some_dir`, the `some_dir` directory itself must belong to the `consult` group. If that's not the case, the directory's owner (alex in your example), should issue the following command:

```
$ chgrp consult some_dir/
```

or to change group ownership of everything inside the directory:

```
$ chgrp -R consult some_dir/
```

This will only work if alex is a member of the `consult` group, which seems to be the case in your example.

This will not allow ben to access all of alex's directories for two reasons:

1. Not all of alex's directories will belong to the `consult` group
2. Some of alex's directories may belong to the `consult` group but alex may not have chosen to allow `rwx` group access to them.

In short, the answer depends both on group ownership and on the group permission bits set for the directory.

All of this is provided you don't use any additional [mandatory access control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandatory_access_control) measures on your system.

Comment: consult_documents is a Directory then how can u specify it as a group ?

Comment: @Babinlonston You can't. You specify `consult` as group.

Comment: Thank you, I was looking how to give access to a directory to one group. I did not realize that the chgrp command could do this. I thought that chgrp was only to add/delete users to a group.

Comment: @anatak Modifying group membership is done via `usermod` not `chgrp`

Comment: Is this the same as `chown -R :consult some_dir/`?

Answer (score 9):

```
setfacl -m g:debian-transmission:rwx -R /mnt/sra
```

Found this command nice, instead of `chown` that will change completely the owner of the file or directory!

You will see on a `ls -Al` that a `+` sign will be added to show that there is more than one owner!

```
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Nov  8 19:11 sdc1/
drwxrwxr-x+  3 root root 4096 Feb 17 19:16 sra/
```

And then you can use `getfacl` to see who can write or read the file or directory!

```
# file: sra
# owner: root
# group: root user::rwx
group::r-x
group:debian-transmission:rwx
mask::rwx
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:group::r-x
default:group:debian-transmission:rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::r-x
```

Comment: cool, thank you

Answer (score 8):

This will make alex and ben to colabrate each other in this Directory, And they can't collab in other Dir..

Modify the User group using

```
# usermod -a -G alex,ben alex
```

Then change the Permission for Folder

```
# chown alex:ben consult_documents
```

Check here i have worked it around

```
$ sudo usermod -a -G alex,ben alex

$ sudo chown alex:ben consult_documents/

cd consult_documents/

$ touch babin

drwxrwxr-x 2 alex ben  4096 Feb 20 15:19 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 alex alex 4096 Feb 20 15:17 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 alex alex    0 Feb 20 15:19 babin

$ su - ben

cd /home/alex/consult_documents/

ben@system99:/home/alex/consult_documents$ touch babin1
ben@system99:/home/alex/consult_documents$ ls -la
total 8
drwxrwxr-x 2 alex ben  4096 Feb 20 15:19 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 alex alex 4096 Feb 20 15:17 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 alex alex    0 Feb 20 15:19 babin
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ben  ben     0 Feb 20 15:19 babin1
ben@system99:/home/alex/consult_documents$
```

[image: Have a look here]

Answer (score 7):

If I understood correctly your question, the answer is yes.

Let me explain:

Your folder and file access rights are divided into three categroies:

```
xxxyyyzzz
xxx are access rights for the owner
yyy are access rights for the owner's group
zzz are the access rights for everyone else
```

Every file and folder must be owned by a user.

Which means, if you have a folder named consult_documents, and you want it to be accessible from everyone of the group Consult, you will have this (with 755 access rights):

```
drwxrwxr-x Alex Consult [......]
```

The directory is owned by Alex, and the group is Consult. Alex has RWX access rights on it. Group Consult has RWX access rights on it. Other users have RX rights.

As your user Alex has several groups, you can choose the group to share with.

For example, if your folder is owned by Alex from groupe Alex:

```
drwxrwxr-x Alex Alex [......]
```

Do it:

```
chown Alex:Consult your_folder
```

It will become:

```
drwxrwxr-x Alex Consult [......]
```

And then the directory is available for the group Consult.

Please note that, as far as I know, you can add a group that is not one of the owner's group. But I'm not sure if it is recommended (not clear when reading access rights).